# Error installing eth-brownie with `pipx install eth-brownie`

Tags: python, solidity

`Fatal error from pip prevented installation. Full pip output in file:
C:\Users\arman.local\pipx\logs\cmd_2023-01-24_23.27.56_pip_errors.log

pip failed to build packages:
bitarray
cytoolz
yarl

Some possibly relevant errors from pip install:
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
cytoolz/dicttoolz.c(209): fatal error C1083: No se puede abrir el archivo incluir: 'longintrepr.h': No such file or directory
yarl/_quoting_c.c(196): fatal error C1083: No se puede abrir el archivo incluir: 'longintrepr.h': No such file or directory

Error installing eth-brownie.`

After I run the line-code above, it outputs this error and I've tried uninstalling and installing pipx again but this just doesn´t work.

Answer (score 2):

This error is generated due to an incompatibility between Python 3.11 and Cython. While it will most likely get fixed in later builds, downgrading to an earlier Python version usually does the trick. Here are a few steps I would recommend:

1. Install Python 3.10 or lower. This can run concurrently with your current Python version, but you need to change the priority version in PATH, use a virtual environment, or directly call it in the shell using `py -3.10`.
2. Uninstall pipx (run `pip uninstall pipx`) and reinstall it using the lower Python version `py -3.10 -m pip install --user pipx`. You might need to clean up earlier attempts to install brownie by deleting the eth-brownie folder under users/your-username/.local/pipx/venvs.
   Also, remember to call `pipx ensurepath` after reinstallation
3. Uninstall Cython (run `pip uninstall cython`) and reinstall it using the lower Python version (run `pip install cython`).
4. Reattempt installing eth-brownie `pipx install eth-brownie`.

If brownie installation still doesn't work, try one or both of the following:

1. Forget pipx altogether and `pip install brownie` instead.
2. Download the Visual Studio Build tools 2019, and install all the dependencies.

Comment: This worked for me. But I completely unintsall Python 3.11 and installed Python 3.10.11 as Python 3.11 is not yet compatible with some web3 libraries. I am sure those conflicts will be resolved in the future the we can upgrade to Python 3.11 or later